# Ubuntu 20.10 VM restarts sometimes after wake from sleep

Tags: suspend, virtualization, 20.10, virt-manager

I'm runing ubuntu 20.04 on the host and Ubuntu 20.10 on two VMs. I always let them open and running. Sometimes, after waking the laptop from sleep, one of them has the screen locked (they both are configured to never lock screen/sleep). Then I put the password and unlock it, the screen gets black and I have to force reset the VM for it to work again.

It's annoying because I then have to reopen everything I was working on.

What can I do to solve this problem? It's not always that it happens and not on both VMs at the same time.

I use virt-manager for the virtualization

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that it might be a problem with ACPI not cooperating with the virtualization software or vice versa, or it might be a problem with files in the virtual machine. Maybe try using different virtualization software, or try using a different version of Ubuntu on the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Setting** and then **Power** option Check the **Automatic Suspend**:

[image: img1]

Or you can check the **Privacy** section and in **ScreenLock** **disable** the **Lock Screen on Suspend**:

[image: img2]

Comment: power suspend is already off and also screen lock on suspend is off

Comment: had you tried Caffeine ? https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/517/caffeine/